# Getting specific basis vectors of the kernel in MatLab

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, systems-of-equations, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

Im interested in getting the basis vectors of the kernel of a given matrix A. I often used `null(A)` which works fine. Im more interested to get exactly the basis vectors that you would get when calculating the homogeneous system of linear equations by hand.

For example `A = [2,-1,-1 ; 0,0,0 ; 2,-1,-1]`. For that MatLab gives me

`null(A) = 
 0.5774         0
 0.5774   -0.7071
 0.5774    0.7071`

I tried to use `kernel(rref(A))` where `rref(A)` is just `[1,-0.5,-0,5 ; 0,0,0 ; 0,0,0]`. For this matrix I do get

`null(rref(A)) =

      0   -0.5774
-0.7071   -0.5774
 0.7071   -0.5774`

When solving the system of linear equations `A*b = 0`using pencil and paper I get

`0.5    0.5
   0     1
   1     0`

as the kernel of A. I want to get the exact same result from matlab. Is there a function that get me there or can someone help me with the coding? From linear algebra I know that `dim(kern(A)) = length(A) - rank(A)` so we can consider the last `r = dim(kern(A))` variables to be free to choose. I would like to choose them to be `1`. How do I get to that basis vectors?

Comment: Have you tried `null(A, 'r')`?

Comment: That solved it already. Thanks alot!